# Does Epiphany/Web support profiles, and if so, where should they be stored?

Tags: release-odin, epiphany, flatpak, web-browser

Previously in Epiphany/Web, you could launch different profiles in new instances using [the --profile flag](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/epiphany.1.html), similar to Firefox. This was handy if, for example, you wanted a separate instance using a different Google/Firefox Sync account. But everything changed when <strike>the Fire Nation attacked</strike> elementary switched to Flatpaks, and this doesn't work any more.

Installing `epiphany-browser` via `apt` and doing `epiphany-browser --profile="/home/USER/.local/share/epiphany/PROFILE"` works. However, using the preinstalled version with `flatpak run org.gnome.Epiphany --profile="/home/USER/.local/share/epiphany/PROFILE"` (or the longer version I found in the .desktop file, `/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=daily --arch=x86_64 --command=epiphany org.gnome.Epiphany`) doesn't work; it just launches an incognito window.

Is there a way to get profiles to work in the Flatpak version of Epiphany/Web? Do they need to be stored in any particular place?

**edit:** <strike>Figured it out myself, the solution is to go into System Settings→Applications→Permissions and give Gnome Web access to Home & System folders! Leaving this here in case anyone else has this problem.</strike> As per [Michael C.'s answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/28588/26780), it only needs access to Home, and profiles are stored in `~/.var/app/org.gnome.Epiphany`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> edit: Figured it out myself, the solution is to go into System Settings→Applications→Permissions and give Gnome Web access to Home & System folders! Leaving this here in case anyone else has this problem.

Well that will work, but it's not safe. This is a web browser, you don't want it to have unlimited system access. The equivalent of ~/.local/share/epiphany under flatpak is ~/.var/app/org.gnome.Epiphany/data/epiphany, so you can just move your profiles there and not worry about giving it extra permissions. Have fun.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know about ~/.var! I've moved my profiles there instead.